# Reset Password Functionality

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I have an api built with Django Rest framework and a Front end that's built with Angular

For the reset password functionality, when the user clicks on the reset password they should provide `email` within a reset password component on Angular.  Then via `submit` action It hits the `POST` method of `reset_password` with the `email` in the body.

Then the reset password controller should send an email to the user with this format `base_url/reset_password/<token>`

When the user hits this url, they should be redirected to a reset password form with `new password` and `confirm password`

The Question is:
Where should this template be stored? Angular component or Django template?

What is the best practice for such case?

Comment: create reset password component and set route `resetpassword` get token from API create authGuard for reset password set on route and redirect on reset page if reset token is valid and send reset password with token in your server and update it.

Comment: It depends on you app architecture. Can you provide the code? I mean, if you made the app with Angular, I guess the end-user should be redirected to a specific page/component you provided for it. don't mess it with django template

Comment: I mean this functionality specifically. @RoiSadika 
Can i just make the `/reset_password/<token>` render a reset form that is stored in the API and do everything for this functionality server side as it will use less requests as i can validate the `token` on the and if failed i render `expired token` template for example.

Comment: @MohamedHamza The reset password functionality should be a call to the API and you should also provide a service in Angular to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with *Angular component* option due to the role of separation between UI and the data when you have a restful backend and a single page app.